# Who is the man in this picture?

Tags: game-identification

[image]

Who is the man in this picture?

Comment: I'm closing this due to there not being any indication of why this might be from a game as per our [rules on game id questions](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10198/127901). Please take this to meta if you disagree

Answer (score 10):

This is the character [Wrench](https://watchdogs.fandom.com/wiki/Wrench_(character)), in Watch Dogs 2.

[image]